# How do you delete a fork on Bitbucket?

Tags: version-control, bitbucket, git-fork

I've forked a repo on Bitbucket, it was a mistake, I want to delete the fork.

Rather than go through the hassle of merging it back in (which would be misleading as I haven't made any changes, anyway) I'd just like to delete it.

I can't see a front-end option in Bitbucket for this, but there must be one... right?

Answer (score 26):

Considering that a BitBucket fork simply create a repo on the BitBucket side, the simplest way to delete said fork is... simply delete the BitBucket repository.

(Update May 2014)

See [Deleting a Bitbucket Repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Delete+a+repository):

1. Log into your Bitbucket account.
2. Navigate to the repository you want to delete.
3. Click the repository's  settings icon.
4. Choose Delete Repository from the left-hand navigation.
   The system displays the deletion dialog.
5. (Optional) Enter a URL in the Redirect to field.
   Future users who try to access your repository are sent to this new URL.
6. Press Delete repository.

Example:

[image: delete bitbucket repo]

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is outdated. @mcs' answer is closer to the current workflow.

Comment: @waldir Sure. I have updated the answer, restore the proper link, and added an illustration.

Answer (score 25):

After spending times on BitBucket trying to delete my repository. I took the time and wrote tutorial like on git

**How to delete Bitbucket repository** - *updated 2017-10-19*

1. Login to **your** BitBucket account.
2. Click on the repository that you want to delete from *right sidebar*.
3. Click on button **Settings** on main navigation bar of your repository.
4. Navigate down and click on button **Delete repository**.
5. Click on button **Delete**.

For the lazy ones here are the images, you know how they say image is like 1000 words.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Atlassian keep changing the UI in the hopes people will stop deleting repositories. It changed yet again.

Today I gave up on bitbucket after they locked me out because their new login system is completely broken unless you allow third-party cookies so they can log you in two dozen sites at once. Thanks, no.

The current, as of **2020-Jul**, position for the delete button is:

```
Repository Settings
  > Repository Details
    > three dots non-descript button on the top right of the page
      > Delete
```

[image]